# TableView`s content does not appear "tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have seen similar threads and read them but I still can't make it work. Thus I decided to post my code here in case someone can help me further. I am trying to create a tableview inside a ViewController. I am using Xcode 4.5 and storyboard.

**prodViewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface prodViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *prodview;

// properties of ui

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *namelbl;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *manufactlbl;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scorelbl;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dscrlbl;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *videolbl;

// properties of tab bar

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *addfav;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *compare;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *more;


// table

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;

@end
```

**prodViewController.m**

```
        #import "prodViewController.h"

        @interface prodViewController ()

        @end

        @implementation prodViewController
  @synthesize tableview;
@synthesize prodview;


@synthesize addfav;
@synthesize compare;
@synthesize more;


@synthesize image;
@synthesize namelbl;
@synthesize manufactlbl;
@synthesize scorelbl;
@synthesize dscrlbl;
@synthesize videolbl;





- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [tableview setDataSource:self];
    [tableview setDelegate:self];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{


    [self setAddfav:nil];
    [self setCompare:nil];
    [self setMore:nil];

    [self setProdview:nil];
    [self setTableview:nil];
      [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}



        @end
```

**TableView Connections:**

[image]

**Error:**

```
[prodViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x683a5b0
2*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[prodViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x683a5b0'
```

**New Error:**

If I remove the implemented table methods, so that storyboards implementations only are valid I still get this error:

```
-[prodViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c34c80
```

Comment: are you calling tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: explicitly from any other controller? Why you have declared table view datasource methods in your header file?

Comment: Nope not yet. But even if I remove them it won't change anything @NagaMalleshMaddali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method names are case sensitive. The first part must be `tableView:...` (`V` is capital letter), but you have all in lowercase: `tableview:...`.

Comment: Thank you I fixed this and it runs properly! But if I remove the implemented methods in the code so that the storyboards changes are applied only, I still get the same error. Whys that?

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the method declarations in the interface file.

The protocol is all that is needed to define a `UITableViewDatasource` or `UITableViewDelegate`.

Are you manually calling those methods from somewhere in your project? The method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` should only be called by the tableview. You shouldn't call it yourself.

**EDIT**

Also, you don't need to set the datasource and delegate in `viewDidLoad` you are already doing this in InterfaceBuilder.

It seems like you're following a very old tutorial here. I'd recommend having a look for a more up to date tutorial.

[Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com) is always a good place to start.

Comment: Through the interface builder no idea why but it didn't work properly.

Comment: @user3211165 please see Aleksejs answer. It is correct. You have used a `v` when you need a `V`.

Comment: I still get the same error when I am trying to apply the changes through the interface builder in storyboard

Comment: @user3211165 LOOK AT THE OTHER ANSWER. THE OTHER ANSWER IS CORRECT. It is nothing to do with Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes I know. But if I use that code I do the updates in the tableview through coding. When I am trying to do it through storyboard (number of rows, cells content etc) I get the same one

Comment: @user3211165 I think you are misunderstanding how a table view works. You can't provide content for a table view in the interface builder. Unless you are using a static table view.

Comment: Oh then thats my fault. I am using dynamic cells. I see now whats wrong. Thank you